# Find all $n$ $\in$ $\Bbb Z^+$ such that: $\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor \cdot \lfloor \frac{n}{3} \rfloor \cdot \lfloor \frac{n}{4} \rfloor = n^2$

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

Find all the numbers $n$ $\in$ $\Bbb Z^+$ such that:

$$\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor \cdot \left\lfloor \frac{n}{3} \right\rfloor \cdot \left\lfloor \frac{n}{4} \right\rfloor = n^2$$

I never worked before with floor function so i'm not completely sure how to solve this. I think (only because $n$ $\in$ $\Bbb Z^+$), i can just multiply (skipping the floor function) and get the answer of $n=24$, but this is floor function so i don't know if there are more solutions.

Any hints?

Comment: It seems to me that the solution of $(\frac {n}{2} -1)(\frac {n}{3}-1)(\frac {n}{4} -1) = n^2$ should provide an upper bound for possible solutions, and this should give a manageable number of cases to check.

Comment: Yep, that's a good starting point. For all $n \ge 33$, we have $(\tfrac{n}{2}-1)(\tfrac{n}{3}-1)(\tfrac{n}{4}-1) > n^2$. Thus, we only need to check $1 \le n \le 32$.

Comment: Using the fact that $x-1\leq [x]<x$, we have $$ \frac{(n-2)(n-3)(n-4)}{24}\leq n^2<\frac{n^3}{24}$$ which implies $24\leq n$.

Comment: And for $n \le 23$ we have $(n/2)(n/3)(n/4) < n^2$.  So we don't need to check $n \le 23$.  It suffices to check $24 \le n \le 32$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You already ofund a solution $n=24$. 
For $n<24$, we have
$$ \left\lfloor\frac n2\right\rfloor \left\lfloor\frac n3\right\rfloor\left\lfloor\frac n4\right\rfloor\le \frac n{24}\cdot n^2<n^2.$$
For $n\ge 30$, we have
$$\begin{align}\left\lfloor\frac n2\right\rfloor \left\lfloor\frac n3\right\rfloor\left\lfloor\frac n4\right\rfloor -n^2&\ge\frac{n-1}2\frac{n-2}3\frac{n-3}4-n^2\\&=\frac{n^3-30n^2+11n-6}{24}\\&\ge\frac{11n-6}{24}\\&>0.\end{align}$$
Hence we need at most check $25\le n\le 29$.

To simplify checks for these cases, note that $\left\lfloor\frac n2\right\rfloor$, $ \left\lfloor\frac n3\right\rfloor$, $\left\lfloor\frac n4\right\rfloor$ are three distinct integers $\ge 6$. As $29^2$ and $5^4$ cannot be written as product of three distinct integers $\>1$, we can exclude $n=29$ and $n=25$. For $3^6$, the only way to write it as product of three distinct integers is as $3\cdot 9\cdot 27$, but $3<6$, so we can exclude $n=27$ as well.
For $n=26$, we see that only one of the three factors is a multiple of $13$, so this can be ruled out as well. Fially, for $n=28$, $\lfloor \frac n3\rfloor=9$, but $28^2$ is not a multiple of $3$.

Comment: (+1) I took too long working on my answer, that I did not see yours, which is essentially the same.

Answer (score 0):

We have

$$
\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor \cdot \left\lfloor \frac{n}{3} \right\rfloor \cdot \left\lfloor \frac{n}{4} \right\rfloor - n^2 =0
$$

Note that:
$$
x > \left\lfloor x \right\rfloor
$$

Thus:
$$
\frac{n}{2}\cdot \frac{n}{3}\cdot \frac{n}{4}  - n^2 >\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor \cdot \left\lfloor \frac{n}{3} \right\rfloor \cdot \left\lfloor \frac{n}{4} \right\rfloor - n^2  = 0
$$

Thus:

$$
\frac{n^3}{24}-n^2= n^2\left( \frac{n}{24}-1\right) >0
$$

Hence we are looking for a number larger than 24.

At the same time:
$$
\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor \cdot \left\lfloor \frac{n}{3} \right\rfloor \cdot \left\lfloor \frac{n}{4} \right\rfloor - n^2 > \left( \frac{n}{2}-1\right) \cdot\left( \frac{n}{3}-1\right) \cdot\left( \frac{n}{4}-1\right) -n^2
$$
Therefore:
$$
0>\left( \frac{n}{2}-1\right) \cdot\left( \frac{n}{3}-1\right) \cdot\left( \frac{n}{4}-1\right) -n^2
$$

This function has only one real root around 32.216 [I'm lazy, sorry about that](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cleft(+%5Cfrac%7Bn%7D%7B2%7D-1%5Cright)+%5Ccdot%5Cleft(+%5Cfrac%7Bn%7D%7B3%7D-1%5Cright)+%5Ccdot%5Cleft(+%5Cfrac%7Bn%7D%7B4%7D-1%5Cright)+-n%5E2).

Hence we are looking for $n$ in the interval $[24,32]$. I'll check it in Python:

```
from math import floor
for n in range(24, 33):
    if (floor(n/2)*floor(n/3)*floor(n/4)-n*n) == 0:
        print(n)
```

And the only answer is 24.

Answer (score 0):

A lengthy approach

As $[2,3,4]=12,$ let us try with all $12$ in-congruent residues $\pmod{12}$

If $n=12k$

$6k(4k)(3k)=(12k)^2\iff k=2$

If $n=12k+1,$

$6k(4k)(3k)=(12k+1)^2$ which is untenable as LHS is divisible by $6$

If $n=12k+2,(6k+1)(4k)(2k)=(12k+2)^2\iff6k+1=2k^2$ which is even

If $n=12k+3,(6k+1)(4k+1)2k=(12k+3)^2 which is odd unlike the LHS

If $n=12k+4,(12k+4)^2=(6k+2)(4k+1)2k\iff4(3k+1)=4k+1$ which is odd unlike LHS

and so on

Answer (score 0):

3 solutions; 24, 25, 26
$${n}^{\mathrm{2}} =\lfloor\frac{{n}}{\mathrm{2}}\rfloor\lfloor\frac{{n}}{\mathrm{3}}\rfloor\lfloor\frac{{n}}{\mathrm{4}}\rfloor \\ $$
$${n}=\mathrm{12}{m}+{k} \\ $$
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}{\boldsymbol{{k}}}&\hline{\boldsymbol{{n}}^{\mathrm{2}} =\lfloor\frac{\boldsymbol{{n}}}{\mathrm{2}}\rfloor\lfloor\frac{\boldsymbol{{n}}}{\mathrm{3}}\rfloor\lfloor\frac{\boldsymbol{{n}}}{\mathrm{4}}\rfloor}&\hline{\boldsymbol{{m}}}&\hline{\boldsymbol{{n}}}\\{\mathrm{0}}&\hline{\left(\mathrm{12}{m}\right)^{\mathrm{2}} =\left(\mathrm{6}{m}\right)\left(\mathrm{4}{m}\right)\left(\mathrm{3}{m}\right)}&\hline{\mathrm{2}}&\hline{\mathrm{24}}\\{\mathrm{1}}&\hline{\left(\mathrm{12}{m}+\mathrm{1}\right)^{\mathrm{2}} =\left(\mathrm{6}{m}\right)\left(\mathrm{4}{m}\right)\left(\mathrm{3}{m}\right)}&\hline{\varnothing}&\hline{\varnothing}\\{\mathrm{2}}&\hline{\left(\mathrm{12}{m}+\mathrm{2}\right)^{\mathrm{2}} =\left(\mathrm{6}{m}+\mathrm{1}\right)\left(\mathrm{4}{m}\right)\left(\mathrm{3}{m}\right)}&\hline{-\frac{\mathrm{1}}{\mathrm{6}}}&\hline{\mathrm{0}}\\{\mathrm{3}}&\hline{\left(\mathrm{12}{m}+\mathrm{3}\right)^{\mathrm{2}} =\left(\mathrm{6}{m}+\mathrm{1}\right)\left(\mathrm{4}{m}+\mathrm{1}\right)\left(\mathrm{3}{m}\right)}&\hline{-\frac{\mathrm{1}}{\mathrm{4}}}&\hline{\mathrm{0}}\\{\mathrm{4}}&\hline{\left(\mathrm{12}{m}+\mathrm{4}\right)^{\mathrm{2}} =\left(\mathrm{6}{m}+\mathrm{2}\right)\left(\mathrm{4}{m}+\mathrm{1}\right)\left(\mathrm{3}{m}+\mathrm{1}\right)}&\hline{\frac{\mathrm{7}}{\mathrm{4}}}&\hline{\mathrm{25}}\\{\mathrm{5}}&\hline{\left(\mathrm{12}{m}+\mathrm{5}\right)^{\mathrm{2}} =\left(\mathrm{6}{m}+\mathrm{2}\right)\left(\mathrm{4}{m}+\mathrm{1}\right)\left(\mathrm{3}{m}+\mathrm{1}\right)}&\hline{\varnothing}&\hline{\varnothing}\\{\mathrm{6}}&\hline{\left(\mathrm{12}{m}+\mathrm{6}\right)^{\mathrm{2}} =\left(\mathrm{6}{m}+\mathrm{3}\right)\left(\mathrm{4}{m}+\mathrm{2}\right)\left(\mathrm{3}{m}+\mathrm{1}\right)}&\hline{\frac{\mathrm{5}}{\mathrm{3}}}&\hline{\mathrm{26}}\\{\mathrm{7}}&\hline{\left(\mathrm{12}{m}+\mathrm{7}\right)^{\mathrm{2}} =\left(\mathrm{6}{m}+\mathrm{3}\right)\left(\mathrm{4}{m}+\mathrm{2}\right)\left(\mathrm{3}{m}+\mathrm{1}\right)}&\hline{\varnothing}&\hline{\varnothing}\\{\mathrm{8}}&\hline{\left(\mathrm{12}{m}+\mathrm{8}\right)^{\mathrm{2}} =\left(\mathrm{6}{m}+\mathrm{4}\right)\left(\mathrm{4}{m}+\mathrm{2}\right)\left(\mathrm{3}{m}+\mathrm{2}\right)}&\hline{\frac{\mathrm{3}}{\mathrm{2}}}&\hline{\mathrm{26}}\\{\mathrm{9}}&\hline{\left(\mathrm{12}{m}+\mathrm{9}\right)^{\mathrm{2}} =\left(\mathrm{6}{m}+\mathrm{4}\right)\left(\mathrm{4}{m}+\mathrm{3}\right)\left(\mathrm{3}{m}+\mathrm{2}\right)}&\hline{-\frac{\mathrm{3}}{\mathrm{4}}}&\hline{\mathrm{0}}\\{\mathrm{10}}&\hline{\left(\mathrm{12}{m}+\mathrm{10}\right)^{\mathrm{2}} =\left(\mathrm{6}{m}+\mathrm{5}\right)\left(\mathrm{4}{m}+\mathrm{3}\right)\left(\mathrm{3}{m}+\mathrm{2}\right)}&\hline{-\frac{\mathrm{5}}{\mathrm{6}}}&\hline{\mathrm{0}}\\{\mathrm{11}}&\hline{\left(\mathrm{12}{m}+\mathrm{11}\right)^{\mathrm{2}} =\left(\mathrm{6}{m}+\mathrm{5}\right)\left(\mathrm{4}{m}+\mathrm{3}\right)\left(\mathrm{3}{m}+\mathrm{2}\right)}&\hline{\varnothing}&\hline{\varnothing}\\\hline\end{array} \\ $$
$${n}=\left\{\mathrm{24},\mathrm{25},\mathrm{26}\right\} \\ $$